# hbs is not define in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, handlebars.js

I have install handlebars for template handling in node.js app and set the engine to hbs but during runtime it says that **ReferenceError: hbs is not defined**.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


app.get('/home',(req,res)=>{
res.render('home');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Its seems you need `hbs` instead of `handlebars` as the second argument of `app.set()`? See: https://medium.com/programming-sage/handlebars-in-node-js-tutorial-a30a41fc6206

Answer (score 1):

you need to install hbs first

```
npm install express-handlebars


const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
```

then set engine

```
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```